# Primary images when Sharing page on Facebook

Tags: facebook, sharing, photos

We have a PHP based real estate template and when we SHARE PAGE on Facebook, the resulting photos to choose from do not include the desired photo(s) to select from. IE we have 10-15 images on this page, and facebook only offers 3-4 as an option to share, none of which we want to share.

Suggestions?

Example http://kemptvillerealestate.com/listings/listing_body.php?id=118521

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have seen some cases that image size and/or aspect ratio did not satisfy Facebook's requirement and those images did not appear on users' wall, timeline or Facebook page.

The best practice is shown [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/howtos/maximizing-distribution-media-content/) and I think this is the latest one. As Facebook design including timeline, news feed and page changes this optimization practice changes accordingly. So be careful catching up the latest specifications.
So far the document describes as follows:

> Use images that are at least 1200 x 630 pixels for the best display on high resolution devices. At the minimum, you should use images that are 600 x 315 pixels to display link page posts with larger images.
>
> If your image is smaller than 600 x 315 px, it will still display in the link page post, but the size will be much smaller.
>
> We've also redesigned link page posts so that the aspect ratio for images is the same across desktop and mobile News Feed. Try to keep your images as close to 1.91:1 aspect ratio as possible to display the full image in News Feed without any cropping.

And when you update images on your pages, make sure you visit [Facebook Debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/) and let Facebook crawler scrape your page again so they will get the latest version of your page content. Or you can do it programmatically as stated [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/using-objects/):

> This Graph API endpoint is simply a call to:
>
> *POST /?id={object-instance-id or object-url}&scrape=true*
>
> The response from this endpoint will be a JSON object that contains all the information about the object that was scraped (the same data returned when the Object ID is read from the Graph API).